# package org.junit does not exist Junit 5

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit5

I tried all options mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403497/maven-error-package-org-junit-does-not-exist)

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.traform</groupId>
  <artifactId>CardsClient</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.17</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
     <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
     <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20200518</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.804</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm running a build from eclipse

I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project Client: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Integration/Client/src/test/java/com/integrations/product/tests/IntegrationTest.java:[3,24] package org.junit does not exist
```

My package structure is src/main/java for source and src/test/java for my tests
From eclipse when I run as Junit test it works fine but it fails to run when I try it with Maven

My maven version number is 3.6
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Help us help you - please share the relevant line of `IntegrationTest.java`.

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use?  Do you get this problem also when you run it from console (without Eclipse) ? it was an issues between JUnit5 & not latest version Eclipse

Comment: @Mureinik I was looking for the issue in the wrong place. My test class had a import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull which I changed to import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was making a Junit 4 import instead of a Junit 5 import for the assert. I changed

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
```

to

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
```

and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Worked for me, also.
In my case I had to add:
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;