# NoClassDefFoundError in JPA 2.1

Tags: java, maven, hsqldb, jpa-2.1

I am getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService Exception

I am using maven 4, jpa 2.1, hsqldb. am i missing something in my pom. i can add it if needed.
it fails in unit tests, maven etc. I have no clue why. when i run it at home, it runs fine without exceptions. please help me in solving this problem

persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="defaultUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">


    <class>com.core.Master</class>
    <class>com.core.Child</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myTestDb" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />

        <!-- insert data using sql file -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="import.sql"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

when i run the following line:

```
    entityManagerFactory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("defaultUnit");
```

it throws exception as below

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService
at org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:65)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at com.jpa.generator.EntityManagerGenerator.create(EntityManagerGenerator.java:12)
at com.core.TestMaster.testSqlInsert(TestMasterContainer.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 37 more
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you include the hibernate core dependency in your pom.xml file?

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: yes i did. I can add my pom too. but i used 4.3.5.Final version

Comment: Can you add your pom to check?

Comment: @VijendraKulhade i have added it in

Comment: @JohnHarris I tried changing version for hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager to 5.1.0.Final, now this throws a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:276)` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since someone else might face this issue I wanted to post how I was able to resolve it.
There were 2 parts to solving this.

1. According to [Maven 3 and JUnit 4 compilation problem: package org.junit does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845990/maven-3-and-junit-4-compilation-problem-package-org-junit-does-not-exist) link; junit should not be having `<scope>test</scope>` 
   Getting rid of that line helps to get maven running the tests.
2. I was getting exceptions from hibernate. This is because another jar had dependency on `<artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>`
   You should find out if any jars have conflict with the jar versions you have. you can check the dependency hierarchy in eclipse by going into "Dependency Hierarchy" tab in your pom.xml
   Typing in the jar name will show all the jars having dependencies for that jar file.

hope it helps!