# Java 6 Enterprise project (WAR) in Maven3 (Modules)

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, java-ee-6, maven-3

I have Java 6 Enterprise project (WAR) in Maven3 created base on

- http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-web-spring.html
- http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/02/18/j2ee-project-structures

with this structure:

- EnterpriseProject (Super POM)

  - ep-model (produces JAR)
  - ep-persist (produces JAR)
  - ep-service (produces JAR)
  - ep-ui (produces JAR)
  - ep-webapp (puts it all together and produces WAR)

with dependencies (->):

```
ep-webapp -> ep-ui -> ep-model
                   -> ep-service -> ep-model
                                 -> ep-persist -> ep-model
```

When I run Enterprise Project goal "package", war is created in EnterpriseProject\ep-webapp\target\ and this war contains
all needed libraries: ep-model, ep-persist, ep-service, ep-ui.

Q1) Is this solutions right?

Q2) How should I add additional modules (how set dependencies)?

- ep-common (produces JAR)
- ep-ws (webservices; produces JAR)

Should I only add ep-common dependency into ep-weapp pom (just for adding ep-common lib to war) or everywhere where I use ep-common?

```
ep-webapp -> ep-ui -> ep-model
                   -> ep-service -> ep-model
                                 -> ep-persist -> ep-model 
          -> ep-common
          -> ep-ws
```

Thanks a lot for tips

My present solution:
EnterpriseProject Super pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ep</groupId>
<artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Enterprise Project</name>
<modules>
    <module>../ep-model</module>
    <module>../ep-persist</module>
    <module>../ep-service</module>
    <module>../ep-ui</module>
    <module>../ep-webapp</module>
</modules>
```

ep-webapp pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../ep/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>ep-webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>webapp</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>ep-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ep-ui pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../ep/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>ep-ui</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>ui</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>ep-model</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>ep-service</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ep-model pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../ep/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>ep-model</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>model</name>
```

ep-service pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../ep/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>ep-service</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>service</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>ep-model</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>ep-persist</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ep-persist pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../ep/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>ep-persist</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>persist</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>ep-model</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q1) Is this solutions right?

Seems a well-structured set of POMs to me.

> Q2) How should I add additional modules (how set dependencies)? [ep-common, ep-ws]

As for ep-commons, I'm guessing it's stuff common to all modules (common types, exceptions definitions and such) — if so, you need to reference it wherever you use it, otherwise Maven won't be able to compile it, as it creates classpath basing on dependencies. I understand your worry (that you have to repeat the dependency many times), but since you use variables `${project.groupId}` and `${project.version}`, you are not running the risk of referencing different version of the same module in different dependent projects.

If you are a Maven purist, and I'll risk a claim you might be, you could add the ep-commons to a `<dependencyManagement>` section of the root POM, but that will only save you one line in each POM (for version).

One notice: if you're going to use the release plugin in future, the "${}" references will have to be replaced by hard-coded group id and version strings, but the plugin takes care of that itself.

As for ep-ws, I'm not quite sure what's there (JAX-WS classes generated from WSDLs?). If only that, then do the same as for ep-commons.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you MaDa for your clear answer. So if I understand correctly I can (if I'm purist :-)) add all dependencies also into root POM into dependencyManagement and remove version from I children where is given dependency used.

I have the last question about ep-ws. Probably I will use SpringWS & JAXB (or Castor) (because I prefer  top-down approach and manual work without generating class by tool and I don't know if it is possible by JAX-WS). Q3 ep-ws depends on ep-model and ep-service (transitively on ep-persist), but generally not on ep-webapp but I need add this dependency into ep-webapp just for adding ep-ws library into war, am'I right?

About dependencyManagement [this blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-of-maven)

Comment: I wouldn't do WSDL-Java mapping by hand, unless it's a purely educational project. It's drudgery - you'll see it quickly. Q3: it's good that nothing depends on ep-webapp (except maybe an EAR project, but you don't list it yet), as this project is an aggregator for others. So, to have ep-ws included in the war, you need to add it to its direct or transitive dependencies. PS: do accept the answer, if you find it helpful.

Comment: About WSDL-Java mapping I completely agree with [Osvaldas Grigas](http://ogrigas.eu/spring/2010/04/spring-ws-and-jaxb-without-a-code-generator). I'm now working on pretty huge project and from re-using point of view is the manual mapping the best possibility I think. About WS: what you mean by "nothing depends on ep-webapp, because now I have ep-webapp -> ep-ui dependecy (see above). If I remove this dependency, no jar is added to war. And secondly I don't want create EAR so I don't know which modul should have defined ep-ui/ep-ws dependency... Thx

Comment: "Nothing depends on ep-webapp" <> "ep-webapp depends on nothing". In your example ep-webapp is the top level container, so nothing depends on it. About WS: I don't know Spring-WS, somehow I developed a false notion that you're going to write your mapping entirely by hand. Forget my remark then.

Answer (score 0):

So I reworked my project and I hope that this is quite ok:

[image: Enterprise Project]

EnterpriseProject super pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ep</groupId>
<artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Enterprise Project</name>

<modules>
    <module>common</module>
    <module>model</module>
    <module>persist</module>
    <module>service</module>
    <module>ui</module>
    <module>webapp</module>
    <module>ws</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>persist</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>ws</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

webapp pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>webapp</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

common pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>common</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>common</name>
```

model pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>model</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>model</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

persist pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>persist</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>persist</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

service pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>service</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>persist</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ui pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>ui</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>ui</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ws pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ep</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprise-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>ws</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>ws</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```