# What is the purpose of including the jersey-bom import scoped dependency in a jersey project?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jersey, jersey-2.0

When generating a [jersey](/questions/tagged/jersey) based project using `the jersey-quickstart-grizzly2` artifact

```xml
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.7
```

The pom generated a `jersey-bom` dependency **which can be deleted**:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

And this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

this is how the maven dependency graph looks like:

[image]

What is the purpose of including the `jersey-bom` dependency in the project ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should not delete the `jersey-bom` from `dependencyManagement`.

A BOM (bill of materials) packages related dependencies so that their versions will work together. You can read more about it in the maven docs on [this page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Because this lives in `dependencyManagement` (not in `dependencies`), it is not actually adding dependencies to your project, it's just centralizing version management. If you are not familiar with the difference, read more in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619732/1415732).

Basically, the BOM allows you to add as many jersey dependencies as you need without worrying about mixing bad versions:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <!-- NO VERSION NEEDED BECAUSE OF THE BOM -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <!-- NO VERSION NEEDED BECAUSE OF THE BOM -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```