# Maven isn't detecting project dependencies

Tags: java, maven

For some reason, I cannot get maven to list or download a dependency for a fresh project. I have used this particular dependency before so I'm not sure why it isn't working now. From my pom file:

```
<properties>
    <splunksdk.version>1.3.0</splunksdk.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ext-release-local</id>
        <url>http://splunk.artifactoryonline.com/splunk/ext-releases-local</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.splunk</groupId>
            <artifactId>splunk</artifactId>
            <version>${splunksdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Yet, when I try `mvn dependency:resolve` it doesn't find anything. (I've checked ~/.m2/repository/ directory and its still empty.)

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Splunk Scrapper 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:resolve (default-cli) @ SplunkScrapper ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    none
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.906s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 17 16:27:25 MDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/239M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can't get a `mvn dependency:tree` to print anything either.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Splunk Scrapper 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ SplunkScrapper ---
[INFO] com.company.project:SplunkScrapper:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.096s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 17 16:28:46 MDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/236M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? I can't spot anything obvious so I'm not sure why it isn't resolving.

Comment: try removing the `<dependencymanagement>` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<dependencyManagement>` tag is not used for defining what dependencies you need. Its used to specify how to configure a dependency (which version, scope, etc) if it is found on the dependencies for a project.

To define the actual dependencies you need to use the `<dependencies>` tag:

```
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.splunk</groupId>
        <artifactId>splunk</artifactId>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

See [differences between dependencymanagement and dependencies in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven) for more information.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for telling me!