# Dependencies in Dependency Management vs Dependencies in Maven versions plugin

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, parent-pom

When I use Maven `versions:display-dependency-updates` to check dependencies updates, I get two sections of result.

1st:

> The following dependencies in Dependency Management have newer
>   versions:

2nd:

> The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [differences between dependencymanagement and dependencies in maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven)

Answer (score 18):

The [Dependency](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) section of the POM defines the artifacts (jars, zip etc) upon which your project depends. i.e. the artifacts that it requires to compile, run etc.

The [Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management) section of the POM is used to manage dependency information.

So for example, in the following pom the JUnit dependency is defined completely in the `dependencyManagement` section of the POM with `version=4.11` and `scope = test`.

In the `dependency` section you simply need to define the JUnit dependency using the `groupId` and `artifactId` and maven automatically picks up the version and scope from the `dependencyManagement` section.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>

    ...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     <dependencyManagement>

     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>junit</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         </dependency>
     <dependencies>
</project>
```

Usually you would define the `dependencyManagement` section in a parent POM, where you define the version and scope for all dependencies. Then in the child module's you simply need to define the dependencies using the `groupId` and `artifactId`. This allows you to centrally manage versions and means you only have to update them in one place.

All of this is far better explained in the maven documentation:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

The [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) is simply listing the versions found in each of these sections, as it is possible in the `dependencies` section to override the `version` that was defined in the `dependencyManagement` section.

Comment: Your answer is much clearer than those : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven. Thank you DB5

Comment: How would you distinguish child POM vs parent pom? Needs some clarification on that.