# DispatcherServlet not found in spring maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a maven project working with spring and for some reason after a clean of the project i don;t get to see my dispatcher anymore. Here is my pom.xml. I suppose the problem is somewhere in the versions of the dependencies again.

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My maven repository is right where it should be, but there isn't any package from spring-web with servlet.DispatchServlet. Everything else looks fine

```
SEVERE: Servlet /HibernateTutorial threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If you use Eclipse, did you try to add the maven folder back to the deployment assembly? Right click on project -> Properties -> Deployment assembly -> Add -> Java build path entries -> Maven libs -> finish -> apply

Comment: A few more things that could be relevant: Which application server, how do you build, how do you deploy, how do you start the service?

Answer (score 0):

`DispatcherServlet` is in the `spring-webmvc` which is already in your pom.xml

Your dependencies are probably included only inside `<dependencyManagement>`.

More information about `<dependencies>` vs `<dependencyManagement`> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven).