# maven multi-module project with jersey & spring

Tags: java, spring, jersey, maven-3

I've been referring stackoverflow questions for quite some time. now i have got one of my own. I'm basically trying to create a Rest webservice with Jersey 2.22.1. I'm using this archetype to create a maven jersey project from section 1.4 [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#new-from-archetype)

```
   mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp \
                    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
                    -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service-webapp -Dpackage=com.example \
                    -DarchetypeVersion=2.22.1
```

This generates a sample rest jersey webservice. Now i want to access mongodb through this webservice. I'm trying to create a separate jar maven project that uses spring to connect to mongodb. its structure is

- com.yuvi.mongo.service
- com.yuvi.mongo.dao

I have a main class inside service which loads spring context , retrieve dao bean n performs db access.

Now i want to connect these two projects.
I created a parent project, included these 2 as its modules and added mongo as dependency in service. but when i try to access package com.yuvi.mongo from my service it shows package not found error. I created two simple maven projects and followed same procedure for creating multi-module projects that was working perfectly. but when i try it here i can't access the package. I'm displaying my pom files here.,

---

**parent pom**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.yuvi</groupId>
  <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>Mongo</module>
    <module>RService</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

---

**Mongo pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.yuvi</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.yuvi.mongo</groupId>
  <artifactId>Mongo</artifactId>
  <name>Mongo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <mongodb-version>1.8.1.RELEASE</mongodb-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${mongodb-version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

---

**RService pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>com.yuvi</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
    <groupId>com.yuvi.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>RService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RService</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>RService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
           <dependency>
        <groupId>com.yuvi.mongo</groupId>
            <artifactId>Mongo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: You need the mongo project in `<dependencies>` with the other Jersey dependencies, instead of `<dependencyManagement>`

Comment: I think you've got this problem of [confusing dependencyManagement with dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven).

Comment: No i tried adding it with dependencies also . in RService pom i included them inside dependencies where jersey container is included. Still it says package not found

Comment: Did you install the mongo project into your local repo?

Comment: it's installed by default right? I'm running mvn install from parent. Isn't it the reactor decides the build order based on dependencies & provides order of build for project modules?. Also after the mongo build is complete i can see the jar in the .m2 maven repo