# Maven: Configure transitive dependency resolution in case of version conflict

Tags: maven, dependencies, transitive-dependency

I have read that the Maven dependency resolution mechanism can replace my specified version (e.g. 1.2.3) by some lower version (1.0.0) if this other version is "nearer" in the dependency tree. I know that I can exclude this behaviour by specifying the version number with square brackets (like [1.2.3]).

I would like to know whether I can globally define the behaviour for version conflicts? Can I globally say that version conflicts are resolved to the newest version of that version conflicts always lead to an error message?

Comment: You can do something similar to what you ask. You can define a generally preferred version .[see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven)

Comment: You can also influence it using dependencyManagement...But globally changing this behaviour (like you suggested) is not yet possible...