# Can't add mysql-connector-bin.jar to pom.xml

Tags: java, mysql, xml, eclipse, maven

I am currently developing a restful api using `jax-rs`. Project is a maven project. I need to add `mysql-connector-bin.jar` to my project. This is the `pom.xml` file that was generated and I added jar file as follows.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.projects.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>messanger</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>messanger</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>messanger</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql-connector</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.38</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.2</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

When I run he project It shows class not found for the jar file I added. Do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql-connector</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

Also always search for meaven dependcies in http://mvnrepository.com to know how to add anything else in the future

Comment: Shouldn't it also be outside the `<dependencyManagement>` section, in the top-level `<dependencies>` section?

Comment: <dependencyManagement> is used to inherit versions to child projects, it will work both ways. You can understand it more in this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven

Comment: Even though I edited as shown above, I still get this error     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Did you download the dependencies by running "mvn clean install" in the terminal or cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<java.version> 11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.target> ${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
     <maven.compiler.Source> ${java.version}</maven.compiler.Source>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.20</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</properties>
```

you need to go to project setting and change the java.version to 11 or the latest one.
[Error "Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later" on Maven compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034953/error-source-option-5-is-no-longer-supported-use-6-or-later-on-maven-compile)