# Java 17 and maven-archetype-quickstart gives error: Source Option 5 is no longer supported

Tags: java, maven

When using the maven command to create a simple Maven project (with the latest versions of maven and java), I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
```

**So, what change is needed to fix this.**  Do I change the maven command or edit the pom.xml file afterwards?

### To reproduce the error

**First verify what versions of Java and Maven you are running.**
At the time of this question, I'm using the latest versions of Maven and Java.
Maven: 3.8.4 and Java 17.0.2
Below are details

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: D:\p\apache-maven-3.8.4
Java version: 17.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: D:\p\jdk-17.0.2
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

java -version
java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

#### Create the maven hello world-like program

I used this command to create the Java maven sample program.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=helloworld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I found the following link which explains this in more detail (if needed).
https://facingissuesonit.com/2017/06/06/how-to-create-maven-java-console-project/.

#### Build the code

Next, build the code and observe the error.

```
cd helloworld
mvn clean install
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
```

Notice the **ERROR**s.

**But, if I switch back to Java 8 (JDK 1.8) and run the maven build command, then the code compiles successfully.**  Below is the successful compile and the maven version and JDK version used that result in a successful compilation.

```
mvn clean install
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: D:\p\apache-maven-3.8.4
Java version: 1.8.0_271, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: D:\p\jdk1.8.0_271\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

**My question is, how do I fix this?**  and **Why does this happen?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later" on Maven compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034953/error-source-option-5-is-no-longer-supported-use-6-or-later-on-maven-compile)

Comment: It was helpful.  It explained how to fix the problem, but didn't explain why the problem occurred.   I tracked it down and provided an answer.  Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because the maven plugin (maven-compiler-plugin:3.1) passes the arguments `-source 1.5 -target 1.5` to the JDK 17 java compiler.

The JDK 17 compiler doesn't support generating code for the Java 1.5 runtime so the error is produced as shown:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile 
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
```

You can see this if you use the `-X` debug flag when running the maven command as shown below:

```
mvn -X clean install
. . . lots of output omitted . . .
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -target 1.5 -source 1.5 -d target\classes -classpath target\classes; -sourcepath src\main\java; -g -nowarn
. . .
```

The fix is to modify the `pom.xml` file so that the maven-compiler-plugin will pass options like `-source 1.8 -target 1.8` (or some higher number) so that the JDK 17 can produce code that is targeted for a version of the JDK that the JDK 17 compiler supports.

For example, to use JDK 1.8, you would add the following to your `pom.xml` file.

```
<properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

The question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60344341/3281336 also might add some more information if you are interested.

NOTE: The 3.1 version of the maven-compiler-plugin is very old (released Apr 2013) based on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin so back then, Java version 1.5 was a viable choice.

Comment: How can you tell which JAVA Runtime a particular system supports/is using?

Comment: eg: How to find JDK version?

Comment: The maven `mvn -X compile` shows the arguments being passed to the java compiler.  To see the version of the file produced use `javap -v target/classes/some-class-file.class` (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/75812575/3281336)

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant, The JDK version is found with `java -version`.  To figure out what version of java was used to compile a class file, you can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096159/3281336

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> -->
        <!-- <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> --> 
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>
```

Comment: This probably depends on the compiler you are using. There might be some supported compilers out which can compile old stuff.