# Dependencies vs DependenciesManagement?

Tags: maven

I have gone through [differences between dependencymanagement and dependencies in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven) but i am still unclear when to use
just `dependencies` tag in parent pom and when to use  `dependenciesManagement` tag ?

My understanding is when my all child modules need to use same dependency version then we should declare the Dependencies under `Dependencies` tag(without `dependencyManagement` tag)

But on other hand if some of the child project need to use different version then we should  declare the Dependencies under `Dependencies` tag(which will be under `dependencyManagement` tag). then Child modules can refer them with overridden version

Is that correct ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a `<dependency>` within `<dependencyManagement>` does not set the specified artifact as dependency for any project – parent or childs. It just states: If you want to use this as dependency then you can use it with these settings (`version`, `scope`, ...) without having to specify the settings again, and again, and ... You can, however, override a "management" setting in a "real" `<dependency>` anytime.

See also [POM Reference, Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management).

There are two options for a parent POM regarding your second paragraph:

1. As you describe correctly:

   ```
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>g-id</groupId>
       <artifactId>a-id</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
2. I'd use this for consistency:

   ```
   <dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
           <groupId>g-id</groupId>
           <artifactId>a-id</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>g-id</groupId>
       <artifactId>a-id</artifactId>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

Your third paragraph is correct..

Comment: Thanks Gerold. I understand usage of 'dependencyManagement', But can you see if my updated understanding about diff b/w `dependencies` and `dependencyManagement` is correct ?

Comment: As you said `.I'd use this for consistency:` i,e.  approach 2 instead of 1 . My point is if I am sure that my all parent/child modules need to use same dependency version then should not I use approach 1 instead of 2 ? Because in approach 2, I have to unnecessarily mention the dependency in child module

Comment: Also can you elaborate 'A dependency setting that overrides an inherited one doesn't refer to it. It stands for itself' ?

Comment: @emilly Re "_I have to unnecessarily mention the dependency in child module_" – No, you don't have to: `g-id.a-id` is also declared as `<project>/<dependency>`. Such it will be inherited by childs (with the version declared in `<project>/<dependencyManagement>/<dependencies>/<dependency>`).

Comment: @emilly Re "_can you elaboate_" – I meant that if you override a dependency inherited by a parent (completely, i.e. all settings) changes to that parent dependency's settings will not be reflected in the overriding dependency. But you're right. If one adds a setting to the parent it is also reflected at the child, so there obviously is a reference. I'm going to delete this sentences. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your comment `No, you don't have to..` Agreed I don't have to here as` g-id.a-id is also declared as <project>/<dependency>. `. But again point is  if I am sure that my all parent/child modules need to use same dependency version then why I would declare the `<dependency>` under `</dependencymanagement>` ? I can just declare it  as `<project>/<dependency>` . Right ?

Comment: @emilly Yes, you can. The choice is yours. But, isn't it likely that there is a `<dependencyManagement>` section (apart from very simple projects)? And if it's already there why not use it? Such being consistent with other managed dependency declarations.