# Maven: How to import dependency of type pom?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I am trying to migrate a java application to maven. There are some dependencies which have been provided as `jar` files so far. One of these dependencies is `jung2`, which is available from the maven repository: [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jung/jung2/2.0.1)

I need all of the provided modules and I do not understand how to declare this dependecy correctly in my `pom.xml` such that all corresponding `jar` files are downloaded and the classes are available at compile time.

This is what my `pom.xml` file looks like right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jung/jung2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
                <artifactId>jung2</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement> 
</project>
```

I also tried leaving out `<scope>import</scope>` and put the dependency into the `dependencies` section. When executing `mvn compile` or `mvn package`, error message occur that the corresponding packages do not exist.

If I additionally add a `dependency` inside `dependencies` but outside of `dependencyManagement`, e.g.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I receive an error about missing version. But as far as I understood, this should not be necessary due to  `dependencyManagement`? If I also add `<version>2.0.1</version>`, then I get the following error message:

`Failure to find net.sf.jung:jung2:jar:2.0.1`

Comment: This is inside a `<dependencyManagement>` section, so either you need to add a `<dependencies>` outside of it refencing it, or you take it out of the dependency management. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven?rq=1

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for your answer, I edited my original post. Adding the dependency outside the `dependencyManager` did not work so far.

Comment: Yes you need to add the type (and maybe the scope, I'm not sure).

Comment: So I should just copy the `dependency`from the `dependecyManagement` section to  `dependencies`? This also does not work, the corresponding packages can not be found when I try to compile / package,

Comment: Add the type as Tunaki mentioned, and try adding '-U' to the mvn command to force Maven to re-resolve the dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

The `dependencyManagement` tag is used generally when you have a multi module project in maven (where you will have parent-child relationship).

If you specify any dependencies within the `dependencyManagement` tag, it would **NOT** actually download the dependencies.
Putting the dependency within this tag simply means that this dependency is available (to download / to use) for the child pom. The child pom will have to explicitly provide the `groupId` and the `artifactId` co-ordinates to download and use the jar to compile its classes.

If you just have a single module project (looks like yours is a single module project) then you can fix this issue by not using the `dependencyManagement` tag.
Simply put your jars in the `dependencies` tag.

For ex:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>def</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>       // This will now download the pom and its associated transitive dependent jars
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pqr</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>    // This will now download the pom and its associated transitive dependent jars
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Like I said before, the `dependencyManagement` tag will mostly make sense to use if you have a multi-module project, which isn't your case.