# How to use a transitive dependency implicitly managed in a parent project?

Tags: maven, maven-3

There is a `dep` library one of the modules (`module1`) of my project depends on. The dependency is declared in a parent's `dependencyManagement` section.

```xml
...
<groupId>group1</groupId>
<artifactId>parent-proj</artifactId>
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group2</groupId>
            <artifactId>dep</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
```

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>group1</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-proj</artifactId>
    ...
</parent>
<artifactId>module1</artifactId>
...
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group2</groupId>
            <artifactId>dep</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

`dep` in turn depends on `subdep` which I want to use as a dependency in another module (`module2`) inheriting from the same `parent-proj`. The point is to make `module2` use the same version of `subdep` `dep` depends on without explicit declaration of the version in my project. However, when I try to add a dependency on `subdep` into `module2` Maven doesn't realize what version of `subdep` has to be used:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>group1</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-proj</artifactId>
    ...
</parent>
<artifactId>module2</artifactId>
...
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group2</groupId>
            <artifactId>subdep</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

```sh
module2$ mvn dependency:tree
...
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for group2:subdep:jar is missing
...
```

Is there a way to use in a child project a transitive dependency implicitly managed in a parent project?

Answer (score 1):

As [`dependencyManagement`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619732/1725096) only defines the constraints (like versions), not the real `dependencies`, why not putting the version alignment in the shared parent pom?

Updating dependency versions may feel odd, but how about a failed build out of the blue, when you neither have the time to find the cause nor to actually fix it.

The owner of `dep` may upgrade its version dependency regarding `subdep` even without letting you know through a version increment of `dep`. You build gets irreproducible.

If your module depends on the API of version 1 of `subdep` then you most oftenly want to do a 'controlled migration' to version 2. If nothing has changed maybe there is also no reason to increment the version number in the first place.

To reduce the pain, I recommend a look into the Maven version plugin:

- http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/

For the discussion about how to tell Maven to "just use latest" see:

- [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30571/1725096)

Comment: Because if I decide to switch to version 2 of `dep` which depends on a newer version of `subdep` such explicitly defined version of `subdep` will override the version of `subdep` from dependency tree of `dep` v.2. So I'll have to realign that explicit definition manually every time I change a version of `dep`.

Comment: "The owner of dep may upgrade its version dependency regarding subdep even without letting you know through a version increment of dep. You build gets irreproducible." - on the other hand overriding a version of `subdep` in `dependencyManagement` I risk having a faulty build because it wouldn't include the version of `subdep` required by `dep`. And because there weren't errors in build time inconsistency of the build would be discovered only during integration tests or even in runtime.

Comment: Yes, when two artifacts (your artifact and `dep`) of one build directly depend on a third (`subdep`) but with two different versions, one will potentially always loose until we have real modules, where these versions can coexist in runtime.

Comment: If you have lots of artifacts where your want to declare a set of versions to be 'compatible', you can do so by introducing a [`BOM` file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).