# How to use a local maven snapshot of another local project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I feel like I must be lacking some very very basic Maven knowledge here. I have a (couple of) maven project(s) and a shared library. This library should be a separate maven project with its own life cycle. I'm trying to import the library into my project using:

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>nl.whatever.com</groupid>
         <artifactId>my_shared_library</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</groupid>
      </dependency>

      ...
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But maven keeps looking in my repro instead of trying to find my local build. And worst of all, it keeps looking for a jar. I get:

`Could not resolve dependencies for project my.project:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact nl.whatever.com:my_shared_library:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT`

What's my rookie mistake? Yes, I did do a clean install of my library project.

edit:

My .m2 directory has a settings file redirecting my local repro to

```
/ws/repro, which contains:
/ws/repro/nl/whatever/com/my_shared_library/1.0-SNAPSHOT/
   my_shared_project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.lastUpdate
   my_shared_project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

and some property files.

edit2:
I don't think it's a duplicate. I looked at the question linked before posting my question. There is no non-maven project or external jar involved here.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the artifact jar is there in your local `.m2` folder in the correct location?

Comment: You say that you ran install, but is your shared library's pom file configure with the information you defined in your dependency?

Comment: I don' think this question is a duplicate of the stated question. This is not about installing external files, but about building a library so that it can be used by other projects.

Comment: @Strelok updated the question based on your comments. My library's pom file matches the versions and names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local repository is usually in `.m2/repository` below the user repository. If You do `clean install` on your library project, it should be installed into this repository (in `nl/whatever/com/my_shared_library/...`). Then you can use it from all other Maven projects on the same computer.

It is furthermore important that the `<packaging>` is correct, i.e. the packaging needs to match the artifact you want to build. If the packaging is `pom` then you only create a pom (like a parent pom or a bom). Leaving out the packaging tag implictely means that you use packaging `jar`.

Comment: Why delete the .lastupdate files and how does that provide me the jar I apparently need in there?

Comment: The lastupdated files prevent you from using a jar because they tell Maven that the jar does not exist. This is common reason for not getting a jar that should be present. Have you looked into your local repository? Does it contain the library you build with "clean install"?

Comment: The clean install creates the 1.0-SNAPSHOT folder, containing the following files: `_remote.repositories`, `maven-metadata-local`, and `my_shared_library-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom`. No jar.

Comment: Does your my_shared_library have an entry <packaging>pom</packaging>? If so, remove it.

Comment: If not, there is obviously some wrong entry in that pom that prevents the project from being build as a jar.

Comment: That.... explains a lot :X. A whole lot... Could you edit your answer so I can accept it? :X

Comment: I added a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You shall try updating your pom.xml with a tag named as `repositories`.

[Maven repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) are the places that hold build artifacts and dependencies of varying types.

A sample maven remote repository tag with its values is:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

To configure multiple repositories you can follow the [guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) and make use of profile in settings.xml as well.

---

On a side note, unless following a hierarchy or making use of specific versions of a library. You should use `<dependencies>` instead of `<dependencyManagement>`, take a look at the [differences between dependencymanagement and dependencies in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven).

Comment: Would expect some reasons from the members downvoting. Or else how do you expect to improve?

Comment: Sometimes it's not the person answering who has to improve, it's the voter.