# Maven MultiModule Project Errors When Run from terminal

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3, multi-module

I am creating a client and a server wrapper for a neural network. The client reads and sends an image to the server who runs the models and responds the results back to client. 
I have created a multimodule project for this reason. When i run client and server from IDE (intellij idea) everything works ok. However when i use maven to build and then run from terminal i get errors.

My main/parent pom.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>gr.enomix</groupId>
<artifactId>imageClassificationWrapper</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<modules>
    <module>Server</module>
    <module>Client</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

My Server pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>imageClassificationWrapper</artifactId>
    <groupId>gr.enomix</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>gr.enomix</groupId>
<artifactId>Server</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

</project>
```

And my client pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>imageClassificationWrapper</artifactId>
    <groupId>gr.enomix</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>gr.enomix</groupId>
<artifactId>Client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

</project>
```

I want all libraries from parent pom.xml to be inherited to both children client and server. 
Then i run from terminal
mvn clean install 
and the project successfully builds without any error.

Then finally i execute

```
   java -cp target/Server-1.0.jar RunServer
```

to run the server and

```
   java -cp target/Client-1.0.jar RunClient
```

to run the client but i get errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/json/simple/JSONObject
    at ImageHttpClient.sendImage(ImageHttpClient.java:78)
    at RunClient.main(RunClient.java:11)
```

from both client and server.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
    at     Handlers.ConnectionHandler.readAndSaveImage(ConnectionHandler.java:39)
    at Handlers.ConnectionHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Maven dependencies are not build in class path??? 
Am i doing something wrong??
Please Help i am breaking my head two days now...

Comment: without reading all the details of your question guess you should find some answers here: :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven

Comment: Looks like you don't add dependencies into final jar. Please check this comment for possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32316071/2960034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies are not included in the `.jar` file and therefore they cannot be found. Hence the `NoClassDefFoundError`

What you have to do is to include the dependencies in your jar, i.e. build a so called "fat jar".

I will not post how to do that, since there are already a lot of posts on stackoverflow. As I see you already have some in the comments.

EDIT: To test if your dependencies have been included, you can open the generated `.jar` file using 7zip.

Comment: That did it thanks a lot. For any other having the same issue i copied the code from   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven   and i have put it inside the main/parent pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ***dependencyManagement*** tag inside parent pom in order to let child poms inherit dependencies.

Check this link

[differences between dependencymanagement and dependencies in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven)

Comment: dependencyManagement will not lead to inheritance of dependencies in child modules. Anyway, this is not the problem. The problem is with building a fat jar.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry for misleading. I guess you need to add dependencies to the chidren anyway

Comment: Exactly the problem is what DeiAndrei and andgalf mentioned. Check my comment at DeiAndrei's reply for solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you develop an standalone Java application, your dependencies are all being used only for the compilation phase. When you want to run your actual code, Java virtual machine needs to have the address of given dependencies to run your code. In order to do that, you've to tell the Java virtual machine explicitly where to find the libraries. You can add all libraries to your `-cp` option like this:

```
java -cp {your-maven-repository-folder}/org/apache/common/commons-io/commons-io-1.3.2.jar:target/Client-1.0.jar RunClient
```

in which {your-maven-repository-folder} normally is in your user's home folder. For example in linux it is `/home/mixtou/.m2/repository`.

You need to specify **all** your dependencies separating them with `:` in linux and `;` in windows.

As you're already using IntelliJ, one simpler solution could be to right click on your `RunClient` or `RunServer` class and select `Run`. By doing so IntelliJ will try to run your project in the `Run panel`  and if you check the very first line in the run output, you should see the exact command that IntelliJ is using to run your code which includes all necessary libraries.

Remember that in an standalone Java applications, no dependency would be included into your jar file. Such an option is only available in applications that are going to be run on an application server as `war` or `ear` file. Of course you can use some maven plugins that merge all your libraries into your jar file (which is normally known as fat jar) and then you would not need to specify anything in classpath, but then your jar file may become too big (depends on the number of libraries you use) and so updating that would be more cumbersome.