# dependency on same version for all included artifacts in a given group

Tags: maven, hadoop, maven-3, hadoop2

I have a project using various hadoop libraries, in which I want to have all dependencies from group **"org.apache.hadoop"** to have same version i.e. **2.7.6,** for even the transitive dependencies.

E.g. **hive-hcatalog-core:jar:2.3.2** - depends on **hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.7.2** , but I want 2.7.6 version of hadoop-mapreduce-client-core to be used explicitly.
Similary for many libraries within org.apache.hadoop.

Edit - I made my stuff work by adding such conflicting dependencies explicitly in my pom.But I was wondering if we could enforce something like this.

Comment: I would recommend to keep the transitive dependencies as they are cause you might not know if those are working correctly together...

Comment: yeah, I agree to your point. But in some cases where I am directly using hadoop-mapreduce-client-core library. I dont want to downgrade to 2.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to change the transitive dependencies (see khmarbaise's comment), you can do so with `<dependencyManagement>`. It allows you to define the version of all dependencies, including transitive ones.

See e.g.

[differences between dependencymanagement and dependencies in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven)