# Customize Dependency Versions in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I want to use **Quartz** 2 dependency with `spring 1.5.2.RELEASE`

There I want to **override** the parent spring pom dependency for the quartz dependency only.

I tried to do this :

```
<properties>
    <quartz.version>2.3.0</quartz.version>
</properties>


<parent> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> **Error:**
>    Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz:jar is missing.

Comment: Since there is no pom dependency of quartz 1.5.2.RELEASE therefore I am getting this error

Comment: You need to use <dependencyManagement> tag in your pom.xml. Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven

Comment: @Habil if I do this no dependency is read it's giving error in whole project

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-quartz` and quartz support in general for Spring Boot is only available since Spring Boot 2. So trying this with 1.5 will not work.

Comment: @M.Deinum that's why I am asking if I can override parent pom dependency or not....though I have mentioned it directly.....`<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>`

It's working in this case

Comment: As stated overriding a dependency version for something that isn't managed is not going to work. Next to that trying to mix jars of different version is something you should never do, it will lead to issues. Overriding versions only works for versions defined in the parent not for included dependencies (unless they are defined in the parent).