# Maven: child module can not Inheritance parent module's dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management

This is my parent pom

```xml
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.fish56</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenModules</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>dao</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.6</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

this is my child module's pom

```xml
    <parent>
        <artifactId>MavenModules</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.github.fish56</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>dao</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I wish the child module could inherit the parent's dependencies, but it failed.

I can not use Lombok or Junit in my child's pom.

And this is my file tree

```
.
├── dao
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── pom.xml
```

I think there should a way the make some dependencies to be shared among all modules, But I can not find the solution.

Comment: The lombok project has not bom which means your usage of the lombok project is simply not working that way. So just remove `<scope>import</scope>` from your parent.

Answer (score 12):

In the parent `POM`, the main difference between the `<dependencies>` and `<dependencyManagement>` is as follows:

Artifacts specified in the `<dependencies>` section will **ALWAYS** be included as dependencies of the child module(s).

Artifacts specified in the `<dependencyManagement>` section, will **only be included** in the child module if they were also specified in the `<dependencies>` section of the child module itself.

Please find more at following link:

[Differences between dependencyManagement and dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven)

Comment: If I agree to this , I have similar kind of setup and really wonder how mvn clean install is successful but IDE (Intellij IDEA ) asks to add dependency in child module

Answer (score 1):

You import a lombok BOM

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and then you try to use it as a dependency. But a BOM is just a list of dependencyManagement entries. It cannot be a dependency of the child project.