# I can't use inherited dependency in my child modules using maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have the following project structure:

I want to use the same dependency (let's call it: `**dep-for-B-and-C**`) in modules B and C.

```
 A
 ├── B
 │   └── pom.xml
 ├── C
 │   └── pom.xml
 │
 └── pom.xml
```

**root 'A' pom.xml:**

```
...
<groupId>my-group-id</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
</modules>
...

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>***</groupId>
            <artifactId>dep-for-B-and-C</artifactId>
            <version>***</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**'B' and 'C' child modules pom.xml:**

```
  ...
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>***</groupId>
    <artifactId>dep-for-B-and-C</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ...
```

If I put `dep-for-B-and-C` as a dependency of A and B then after I run `mvn clean install`, I got the following error:

```
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for ***:dep-for-B-and-C-jar:jar is missing. @ line 39, column 21
```

If I don't put the dependency (I'm using dependencyManagement so it should place but I don't need to specify version (this is my understanding)) into my child pom.xml then, I have a compile error because I can't use my dependency.

Please note that I have spring-boot-starter-parent as a parent for B and C, because project B and C will be a Spring boot project. The reason why I don't put this in the root (A pom.xml) is that maybe I will have another module that won't be Java project.

**This can be the reason?**
If yes, then should I create a project structure like this?

```
A
├───Backend
│    ├── B
│    │   └── pom.xml
│    ├── C
│    │   └── pom.xml
│    │
│    └── pom.xml (spring-boot-starter as parent)
│
├───Frontend (using: eirslett mvn plugin)
│
└──pom.xml
```

Comment: I also read these, but can't found the proper answer to my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55954293/maven-child-module-can-not-inheritance-parent-modules-dependencies
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712865/maven-cannot-resolve-dependency-for-module-in-same-multi-module-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
```

in modules **B** and **C**. Please add module **A** as parent of **B** and **C**

Comment: Thank you. So seems like I should create a new project structure as I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use A as parent POM, then cannot use dependencyManagement from A.