# Type grid does not have type parameters

Tags: vaadin

I began to study Vaadin and wrote the code as stated in the tutorial:

```
List<PatientEntity> personList = new ArrayList<>();
Grid<PatientEntity> grid = new Grid<>(PatientEntity.class);
```

I got errors in the second line

> Type 'com.vaadin.ui.Grid' does not have type parameters" () and "Diamond operator is not applicable for non-parametrized types" (<>)

Dependencies from `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
           <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
           <version>13.0.11</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
           <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

[image: xxx]

Answer (score 4):

> Type 'com.vaadin.ui.Grid' does not have type parameters

This is not the correct package. I think this is the grid from Vaadin 8. Try `com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid`

---

Edit: adding @Tazavoo's comment into my answer, as it might very well solve your problem.

Have you added a Vaadin dependency to your pom.xml? Adding it to `<dependencyManagement>` does not actually add it as a dependency. You should keep the `vaadin-bom` there, as it will control the versions, but move vaadin-core to your actual `<dependencies>` tag.

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
           <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
           <version>13.0.11</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>    
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
       <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

With this pom structure your IDE should automatically suggest the correct Grid import to you (after you remove the incorrect import statement of course)

Comment: Also, are the dependencies only in `<dependencyManagement>`, or are they listed as actual dependencies as well? The `vaadin-core` dependency doesn't belong in dependency management.

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'flow' ... i wrote "import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;" in header of class

Comment: Have you added a Vaadin dependency to your `pom.xml`?

Adding it to `<dependencyManagement>` does not actually add it as a dependency. You should keep the `vaadin-bom` there, as it will control the versions, but move `vaadin-core` to your actual `<dependencies>` tag, see this for reference https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow/blob/v13/pom.xml

Comment: i dont understand what you said

Comment: @кириллбалашов https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280943/3441504 here the difference between `dependencyManagement` and `dependencies` is explained further. If you can't or don't want to understand it, just do the same in your `pom.xml` file as my code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but you should try to remove the PatientEntity.class from the constructor
(as in the second exemple of vaadin)

Comment: That is not the issue here, passing the PatientEntity.class to the constructor is perfectly fine.