# Maven dependency Issue for Spring Hateoas

Tags: spring, maven, spring-hateoas

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>0.23.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I have added this Spring hateoas dependency in my `pom.xml` still my project is taking version as `0.25.1`. I want version `0.23.0`.

Comment: Please post your full pom.xml

Comment: What Spring Parent version you are using?

Comment: It might be possible that other dependency uses the `hateoas 0.25.1`.

Answer (score 0):

For checking what dependency 'win' You can lunch

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas::
```

I recommended you to read https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Focus on `<dependencyManagement>` tag, which allows You to control transitive dependency(I think this cause your problem)

See [Differences between dependencyManagement and dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven)