# Can not import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder in order to use EqualsBuilder

Tags: java

I need to use EqualsBuilder in my class, for that I need the jar
in my pom I added the following line

```
   <properties> 
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId> 
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
```

and my dependency is after the properties tag

and in my java class I tried to import the jar 
`import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder;`
Eclipse is giving error as well as when I try to run maven

> [ERROR]
>   /C:/git_project/cis/ipnd/src/main/java/au/com/internode/domain/AbstractObject.java:[9,32]
>   package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist

Basically nothing related to lang comes up as a suggestion  when I keep on typing in eclipse after org.apache.commons

Comment: Where did you add the `<dependency>` tag? Inside `<dependencyManagement>`? If so, move it. See e.g. [Differences between dependencyManagement and dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2619598/5221149).

Comment: Did you "Maven > Update Project..." after you modified your pom? Do you see the jar in "Maven Dependencies"?

Comment: As a workaround I had to add this jar, but I need proper solution, how do I get it from Maven

Comment: yes, I did update, I saw the jar

Comment: hi @andreas I have added my code udner <dependency> tag

Comment: I was asking where the `<dependency>` tag is. I can already see that you have `<groupId>`, `<artifactId>`, and `<version>` inside `<dependency>`, but where in the `pom.xml` did you add `<dependency>`?

Comment: hi @andreas, I have added <dependency> after <dependencies> tag which comes after <properties> tag in pom <properties> 
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>   
  </dependency>

Comment: @SadiaH How about you *edit* the question and add the information there, for all to see, in a format that's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

A snippet from pom.xml looks OK to me. 
I don't have a vast experience with eclipse but I suggest using the following. In general there are 2 things that can go wrong here

1. Maven part
2. Eclipse synchronization part

So to eliminate an issue in step one, run `mvn clean compile` in command line even without Eclipse. If it ends successfully, the issue is with the seconds part. In this case re-import the pom into eclipse and it should work (maybe there is a "refresh" button there as well).

If the issue is in "1" and the `mvn clean compile` fails on that import - then please post the whole pom, and probably we'll find a mistake