# DependcyManagement or dependencies ?? in pom maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

According to the maven docs [Dependency management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)

> is a mechanism for centralizing dependency information.

and from this question here [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven), many people suggested to use `Dependency managmement` instead of `dependencies` when we have a common jar file for all children.

as in `dependency management` , dependencies are propogated only when children request for it but incase of `dependencies` the dependecies are propogated even when not required.

but wouldn't it be a better approch when the jar file is common to all children ,i.e when all the children inherit the same jar file

for example (rewritten example taken from maven docs)

**child a**

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-c</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**child b**

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-c</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

***parent of both a and b***

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

---

but wouldn't this yeild the same result ??

***parent of both a and b***

```xml
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**child a**

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-c</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**child b**

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-c</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

or did i misunderstand them??

and which one should i use and in what conditions ??

Answer (score 0):

Dependency management section in the parent pom is managing versions and only versions of these libraries, when you are using them in the child projects.

Dependency section on the contrary ENFORCES all child modules to have these dependencies, regardless child modules need them or not.

If you are sure ALL your child modules will use `group-a:module-a:version`, then feel free to declare it in parent `dependencies` section.

If you have at least one child module in the project, where such enforced dependency is unnecessary, then `dependencyManagement` better suites your need.

Comment: so if all the children needs them would it be better to use `dependencies` then??

Comment: so the only cost with `dependencies` is the unwanted inheritance correct?? i.e it's same same as `dependencyManagement` in every other sens?

Comment: @ursa DependencyManagement does not only handles the versions it can also being used to handle exclusion at a central location and that's one of the reason to use dependencyManagement. Furthermore you have a central location in a project to define the versions of all what you are using.

Comment: @Hummingbird exactly.

Comment: @khmarbaise while technically it is possible to manage exclusions, it could bring you a debug nightmare, if your project is a library used by other projects (with different root pom and exclusions).

Comment: I don't understand your relation to debugging? If you have to have exclusion that has usually a good reason to do so. Furthermore what do you mean by "..with different root pom and exclusions" ?

Comment: I mean libraries development, that are used by multiple teams outside of your project or company. "debug" = resolving client problems caused by dependency inconsistence. The simplest example - you've excluded commons-logging from all your dependencies and used slf4j in your library. However client added Spring Framework and hence commons-logging was also added transitively. Almost harmless bug. However other dependencies could lead to more dangerous consequences.