# "No junit.jar" error in Intellij when right clicking a folder, but not when running individual classes of tests

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

My Spring boot application has several tests classes.

When right-clicking a test class, and selecting the option to `Run XYZtest` it works with no problem.

But when selecting the folder that contains that class and selecting `Run test in com.example.my` I get an error of No junit.jar:

[image]

When running all the tests from mvn they run with no problems.

Following some suggestions, I added the `junit.jar` specifically in the `Library` section, but it didn't help:

[image: "]

Comment: Try Invalidate Cache and Restart File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...
Also, Try reloading the maven project from.

Comment: @rimonmostafiz yes. I tried it, but it didn't help.

Comment: Make sure you have junit library of the right version added to every module's dependencies where you have junit tests. In case of Maven-based project - check that the junit dependency is present in every module's pom.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem, this is how I soloved it:

Context:

- SpringBoot application
- Use maven to manage multiple modules
- Add `junit`'s maven dependency in root POM's `dependencyManagement`(rather than `dependencies`, their differences can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2619732/8706905))
- Intend to test class or folder inside one of the root module's child module

PS: If your situation does not match the context above, this solution may not solve your problem.

Steps

1. right click at the class or folder you want to test:
   [image]
2. Choose `More Run/Debug` -> `Modify Run Configuration`
3. Change the module option to **the one you want to test** from root module
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot is using JUnit 5. If you use the spring boot initializr website, you should have a dependency like this.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Did you use JUnit 4 or 5 in your tests ? You can try to update IntelliJ or JUnit plugin, this may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by adding the Junit Maven dependancy in the root pom.xml file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31858417)