# Javax Persistence unable to compile on maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, pom.xml

I have the following Java code which errors on when I run

```
mvn clean install
```

In my source code, I have the following imports

```
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
```

and in my pom.xml I had the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and I was getting the following error

```
error: package javax.persistence does not exist
```

I thought that maybe there was an error with the entry in the pom, so I tried to change the pom to the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and I still get the following error. I am not sure what's causing the issue and how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure it is put under build/dependencies instead of dependencyManagement ? Or, could it be declared as `runtime` scope?  Check by doing `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: All of my other dependencies are in dependencyManagement  but when I moved it out of there into build/dependencies it worked. Not sure why they were in dependencyManagement in the first place? What's the use of adding them there?

Comment: in short, dependencyManagement is NOT dependency.  you can treat it as some pre-defined settings for a dependency, WHEN you are adding such dependency.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace it with

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```