# Why the dependency in dependencyManagement is not listed out when running mvn dependency:tree

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

Why the `dependency` in `dependencyManagement` is not listed out when running `mvn dependency:tree`?

I have the same question for the `artifactItem` in `maven-dependency-plugin`->`configuration`->`artifactItems`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dependency:tree` shows the tree of project dependencies. If an artifact is only defined in the `dependencyManagement` section, it's not a dependency of the project yet, it's basically only configured as kind of a template. Likewise, `artifactItems` only belong to the configuration of the `maven-dependency-plugin` and its configured executions, but are not project dependencies.

Comment: For a more detailed explanation of the difference between `dependencies` and `dependencyManagement` have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven?rq=1