# Using dependency management in a child pom

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

Is there any reason to use the dependency management section in a child pom? I'm looking at a maven project in my organization that uses inheritance and aggregation, where the parent and child poms both have a dependency management section. Is the child one doing anything?

I found this question really helpful but didn't find the answer to my specific question - [Differences between dependencyManagement and dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven)

Comment: For the life of me, when I first read the question title, I thought that there was an "r" in "pom". Thankfully, I was wrong

Comment: I used to have a "pom⭐️" shirt, I should do another run.

Comment: omg that is hilarious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be used to control the version of transitive dependencies (libraries that your direct dependencies depend on) without adding a direct dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Child POM will add or override dependency management entries of the parent POM.

Keep in mind that you really, really don't want to have different versions of the same dependency in your codebase. So use this feature judiciously. Preferably you should have organization-wide parent POM file with all dependency versions defined and child POMs don't change them.

Answer (score 1):

In a child pom it does not make sense.

In a multi module setup you should control everything for all children in the parent. For example solve version conflicts / excluding transitive dependencies or import BOM files from other frameworks/libraries (for example spring boot/junit 5/etc.) makes handling of those libs including the centralised maintenance location...