# Cannot resolve symbol 'owasp', import error in intellij

Tags: owasp, esapi, crlf-vulnerability

I want to use ESAPI in my project and have added following dependency in the `pom.xml`

pom.xml with dependency:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.owasp.encoder</groupId>
                <artifactId>encoder</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

But when I import `org.owasp.esapi.*` intellij give me warning as shown in image.
[image]

I want to use ESAPI logger to prevent CRLF injection possibilities in log statements.
My current project uses `slf4j.Logger`

I am very new to this ESAPI and OWASP and have never used it and have tried from here
https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/wiki/Using-ESAPI-with-SLF4J#configuring-esapi-to-use-slf4j

Please tell me if im doing something wrong and how to correctly use ESAPI in project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found that I was adding this dependency in `<dependencyManagement>` tag instead of `<dependencies>` tag, that's why it wasn't downloading from the repository.

Previous:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

after fix:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Whats the difference in `<dependencies>` and `<dependencyManagement>` please refer this [Differences between dependencyManagement and dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven)

Comment: Ah, glad you figured it out. Based on the context of what you originally showed, it wasn't obvious that this was in the <dependencyManagement> section, but the fact that the ESAPI jar wasn't showing up in your local Maven cache under $HOME/.m2 was a good clue.

Comment: yes, it was by your suggestion about the pulling jar that i went deeper and found the actual problem. Thanks for your finding. Otherwise it was very frustrating why it was not downloading. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. What JDK are you using with IntelliJ? Java 8 or later is required as of 2.4.0.0. That's the only thing that I can think of that would cause this behavior. Looks okay otherwise. Did you check if the esapi-2.5.0.0.jar got pulled down? Because it's either not finding that or it's not compatible with the Java version that your IntelliJ IDE is using.

Comment: i'm using jdk8 and and my pom.xml file doesn't show me error for dependency when synced, i checked in external libraries in project structure and it is not present there.

also checked local repository in .m2 not there also, not sure why it is not being downloaded in local repo