# org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder failing on Spark3.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dependency-management

I am trying to upgrade from Spark 2.4 to Spark 3.2 version.
`import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder` is working on Spark 3.1 and fails on Spark 3.2 with error `object client is not a member of package org.apache.http`.

Comment: Maybe HTTPS instead of HTTP? I am not a field expert though.

Comment: You need to explain us more your setup: when do you get this error? Compilation, right? What's your build definition?

Comment: Wild guess: you're not explicitly defining the version of Apache HTTP client you want to use (and this maybe make sense if it's provided by Spark) and thus the version of HTTP client changed between the two spark versions and the imports as well. Check out the version of Apache HTTP client being provided and adapt your code for it.

Comment: Managed to reproduce https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/PukZcEzyQzqYlTbbMBo5kw/1 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/PukZcEzyQzqYlTbbMBo5kw/2

Answer (score 1):

The class `org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder` is from `"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient"`

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient

You should add

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.14"
```

to `build.sbt`. Then `import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder` will compile.

(In the 5th version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5 this class is absent.)

---

Here is explanation of the reasons.

In **Spark 2.4.8** `"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient"` is in the root `pom.xml` (`<dependencyManagement>`) and not overridden for example in `spark-core` `pom.xml`

```
<!--  org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-->
<commons.httpclient.version>4.5.6</commons.httpclient.version>
...

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>${commons.httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.8/pom.xml#L499-L503

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.8/core/pom.xml

In **Spark 3.2.0** this dependency is also present in the root `pom.xml` (`<dependencyManagement>`) but overridden for example in `spark-core` `pom.xml` (`<dependencies>`) so that the scope is `test`

```
<!--  org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-->
<commons.httpclient.version>4.5.13</commons.httpclient.version>
...

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>${commons.httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- at least just for tests, coerce SBT to use the updated httpcore/client version -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.0/pom.xml#L622-L626

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.0/core/pom.xml#L370-L375

So if you need this dependency not only in `test` scope you should add it manually.

[Differences between dependencyManagement and dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven)